# how Content Navigator handles data-dojo-config

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

Let's say that I'm developing a simple standalone dojo application. Within the html script tag, I have to mention

```
dojoConfig= { parseOnLoad: false or true, async: true };
```

this way dojo identifies how to load all .js files and whether to parse html pages to widgets (based on true or false of parseOnLoad). I need to do same if I happen to develop another stand alone dojo application. Now with ICN, when we create a plugin, we don't specify the above configuration anywhere. So wanted to know, how and where ICN declares this?

Hope this time I'm more clear.

Answer (score 0):

got to know that it is handled in the header.jsp file under navigator.war